# Как превратить map<String,String> в объект класса?

Tags: java

Есть map описывающий сущность, где пара  это имя поля и его значение. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какой нибудь инструмент который позволит автоматически конвертировать эту мапу в объект соответствующего класса?

Comment: Пара-тройка решений есть тут: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16428817/3432401

Comment: @Regent спасибо, это то что нужно

Comment: Если названия ключей неизвестны заранее, то можно воспользоваться генератоами классов, например `square/javapoet`. Эта штука может создать POJO классы во время выполнения программы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POJO класс все равно придется описать самостоятельно.
Конвертировать можно, например, через Jackson метод [convertValue](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class)):

```
mapper.convertValue(map, MyPojo.class);
```